# How to save a customer custom_attribute value programmatically in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have setup the custom attribute according to [this post](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1238). However I created a plugin of type `<type name="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface">` to save my `example` custom_attribute. My plugin looks like this:

```
public function aroundSave(CustomerRepository $customerRepository, \Closure $proceed, CustomerInterface $customer)
{
    $customer->setCustomAttribute('example', 'a hardcoded value');
    return $proceed($customer);
}
```

The problem I get is that it does actually save the custom_attribute, but the customer created cannot be logged in since the password is not saved in the db. It also takes more than usual to create such a customer so I suspect of an infinite loop going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best practice to name your first parameter $subject for an around plugin and $proceed for your second parameter. It looks like you aren't doing anything after calling proceed() so really you should be using a before plugin. So to do what you need to do, your plugin should look like this:

```
public function beforeSave(CustomerRepository $subject, CustomerInterface $customer)
{
    $customer->setCustomAttribute('example', 'a hardcoded value');
    return $customer;
}
```

Magento has a decent guide on how to use plugins on their documentation site:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#plugin-example

Comment: That is what I needed, the problem was returning the result of the $proceed. I went through Magento Core code and when you return something it gets rid of the password, which I think is a bug.

Comment: For an around plugin you are supposed to return the proceed method as a variable after you have used that variable to modify the result of the original method you are writing the plugin for. Had you not passed $customer as a parameter when returning $proceed(), your plugin should have worked.

Comment: I understand, but that is not the case. If you return the customer to Magento, then Magento overwrites the request which is an array with a Customer object and a password hash with an array with only the Customer. Therefore the Customer is created but without a password. I am not saying my code could be better, all I am saying is that Magento has a bug there.